# How to declare a 2D array to store pictures (using picture boxes)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I am designing a Breakout style game for a project that I am currently working on. I have just finished implementing the ball and the paddle and am having some trouble implementing the bricks for the game. I have a picture of a brick that I want to put in the game. For this, as I need a grid of bricks, I was thinking of declaring a 2D array of pictureboxes (so I can assign the picture of the brick) but I have only been able to declare the array. This is the line of code I have:

```
Dim Bricks(9, 9) As PictureBox
```

So, my question is: How do I access each picturebox and assign the image of the brick? and is there a quicker way to do it? Thanks, your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: [**Arrays in Visual Basic**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) and [**For Each...Next statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that after you create the `Bricks` array, this array is still empty, i.e. all its elements are `Nothing`. You will need to assign the PictureBoxes that are on your form to this array, unless you want to go the other way round and create the picture boxes dynamically.

In the first case do something like this:

```
Bricks(0,0) = pictureBox1
Bricks(0,1) = pictureBox2
...
```

Or with loops

```
For x As Integer = 0 To 9
    For y As Integer = 0 To 9
        Bricks(x, y) = Controls("pictureBox" & (10 * x + y))
    Next 
Next
```

Or `(10 * y + x)` depending on the order you have chosen.

In the other case (create the picture boxes automatically)

```
For x As Integer = 0 To 9
    For y As Integer = 0 To 9
        'Create and initialize the PictureBox
        Dim pb AS New PictureBox
        pb.Size = New Size(30, 30)
        pb.Location = New Point(20 + 30 * x, 20 + 30 * y)
        pb.Image = myinitialImage
        AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf HandlePictureClick

        'Assign the PictureBox to the array
        Bricks(x, y) = pb

        'Add the PictureBox to the Form
        Controls.Add(pb)
    Next 
Next
```

Now you can assign a picture like this

```
Bricks(x, y).Image = myPicture
```

Comment: @oliver thank you very much for the help. However, I was wondering whether I will be able to centre the array of bricks. Currently, the array comes up on the form, but the first brick is on position (0, 0). So, the entire array is located on the top left side of the form. How would I be able to change this so that the array is in the middle of the form?

Comment: Note that the array is just a structure in memory and is not on the form. It Just holds references of controls that are on the form for easier access to the bricks. The easiest way to achieve this, is to place the bricks on a panel instead of directly on the form. Then remove all the anchors of the panel and place it on the center of the form. When the form resizes, the panel will automatically stay in the center.